# Why does Localhost:3000 points to default page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, localhost

I'm new to Rails. With rails running, opening `localhost:3000` takes me to default "welcome aboard" page.
Rake routes command puts out a message that I don't have any routes defined, but I didn't change anything in `config/routes.rb`.

I tried to download back my github repository, but the problem persists. Any idea, please?

@MarcinAdamczyk, @RichPeck. I should say that localhost did work before. this is what I have:

1)
    Pinteresting::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :pins

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :installs
root "pages#home"
get "about" => "pages#about"
```

2)
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
   end

def home
  end

3)
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

```
def about
```

end
   end

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails <4 then you need to remove `index.html` from `public` folder and set `root to: 'controller#method'` in `config/routes.rb`

If its Rails 4 then only setting root route should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

You'll need to change your routes to have the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index"
```

You can then create & corresponding controller action:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
Test
```

This should fix your immediate issue, judging from what you've posted.

Comment: @MarcinAdamczyk. thanks for trying to help, but it didn't work. surely because of poor info I had -- and my being a rookie to RoR. added some more info... I also also consider going advise on how I can go back to the previously good working app that i can retrieve from github.